# How to change default session in Ubuntu 18.04 gdm3?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, gdm

I'm trying to figure out how to change the default session in Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome. By default for any new users, "ubuntu" is selected.

How can I change this to "ubuntu on wayland"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and UNIX & Linux StackExchange cover general questions.  https://askubuntu.com/search?q=%5Bgnome%5D+default might help.